# Get the inner text by ID or any other way C#

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

Hello folks thanks for reading my question in advance. i have a webbrowser in my windows form application in c# and i am going to a website to get the innertext after a quick query. the HTML is the following.

```
<div>
<p id="WSS_COURSE_SECTIONS_1">Fall Semester 2015</p>
<label class="hidden" for="WSS_COURSE_SECTIONS_1"></label><input type="hidden" name="WSS.COURSE.SECTIONS_1" value="Fall Semester 2015">
</div>
```

and i wanted to get the inner text by using the WSS_COURSE_SECTIONS_1, but i already have tried using the following code

```
HtmlElement s1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("WSS_COURSE_SECTIONS_1");
string s = s1.InnerText;
```

But when i check the containing values in the s1 it contains "null"

How can i get "Fall Semester 2015".

Thank you again folks.

Comment: Guys my bad, i wasnt getting the innertext because at the time that i was trying to get the data the webbrowser havent finished loading the webpage. I used that code 
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("WSS_COURSE_SECTIONS_1").Innertext;
and it worked.

Remeber to set the event handler to wait until the page loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wasnt getting the innertext because at the time that i was trying to get the data the webbrowser havent finished loading the webpage. I used that code webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("WSS_COURSE_SECTIONS_1").Innertext; and it worked. Remeber to set the event handler to wait until the page loads